# Lookup variable value from string in shell script

Tags: bash

In bash, if I have:

```
y=10
x='y'
echo $x # prints 'y'
```

Now I want to get `$y` via $x:

```
echo ${$x} # error: "bad substitution"; I want to print 10
```

How do I lookup the variable value with name `$x`?

Comment: Check [eval](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/basic-bash-how-to-use-eval-to-evaluate-variable-names-made-of-arbitrary-strings-775622/)

Comment: @m0skit0 please, no eval -- it has substantial security implications, as documented at http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048. The right way, indirect variables, is documented at http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006

Comment: Everything has good and bad uses. You just have to know how to use it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See Parameter Expansion in bash manual:

```
echo ${!x}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `eval` for [indirect references](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/ivr.html) while escaping the outer dollar sign

```
eval echo "\${$x}"
```

To assign to a variable

```
eval "z=\${$x}"
echo "$z"
# 10
```